# Prove that $c^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ for $c > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I can show a straightforward $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that when $c > 1$, $c^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$. But not when $c < 1$?

WTS

For all $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ st. for $n \geq N$, $|c^{1/n} - 1| < \epsilon$

When $c < 1$, the absolute value can be removed and the inner expression changed to:

$1 - c^{1/n}$. We can temporarily set this $< \epsilon$, and see if a useful expression for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$ comes out:

$1 - c^{1/n} < \epsilon$

$1 - \epsilon < c^{1/n}$

$\log_{c}(1 - \epsilon) < \frac{1}{n}$

$log_{1 - \epsilon}(c) > n$.

The final expression is not terms of $\text{"something"} < n$, which is usually expected. What might be wrong with what I showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logarithmic functions are increasing when the the base is greater than $1$, but *decreasing* when the base is less than $1$.  Thus when you take logs base $c$ with $c\lt1$, the inequality $1-\epsilon\lt c^{1/n}$ becomes $\log_c(1-\epsilon)\gt{1\over n}$, which inverts to $\log_{1-\epsilon}(c)\lt n$, as desired.

Comment: I see that the log is decreasing, in this case, but why does that warrant flipping the inequality?

Comment: @Muno, if $f$ is a decreasing function and $a\lt b$, then $f(a)\gt f(b)$.  That's what it means to be decreasing.

Answer (score 3):

Note that since $\epsilon > 0$ we have $1-\epsilon < 1$ and hence $\log(1-\epsilon) < 0$. Thus you have to flip the inequality when you multiply by $\log(1-\epsilon)$.

Comment: Ah I understand now that $log_{c}(1-\epsilon) < 0$. A quick question concerning flipping the inequality direction:

Comment: I've always understood $x < 7 \iff -x > -7$ to be a consequence of the fact that if $x - 7 < 0$, then it must be true that $-(x - 7) = 7 - x > 0$ and, hence, $-x > -7$. What's the analog here for logs? I don't believe that we're simply multiplying this expression by $log(1 -\epsilon)$

Comment: @Munu. You're actually dividing by $\log_c(1- \epsilon)$ (same as multiplying by inverse) and multiplying by $n$ to get $n> \frac{1}{\log_c (1 - \epsilon)}$.

Answer (score 0):

(very unoriginal)

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+a/n)^n
\ge 1+a
$
so
$(1+a)^{1/n}
\le 1+a/n
$.

If $c > 1$,
let
$c = 1+a$.
Then
$c^{1/n}
= (1+a)^{1/n}
\le 1+a/n
\to 1
$
as
$n \to \infty$.

If
$0 < c < 1$,
let
$c^{1/n} = \dfrac1{1+b}
$.
Then
$c
= \dfrac1{(1+b)^n}
\le \dfrac1{1+nb}
\lt \dfrac1{nb}
$
so
$b < \dfrac1{nc}
$
and
$c^{1/n} 
= \dfrac1{1+b}
\gt \dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{nc}}
= \dfrac{nc}{nc+1}
= 1-\dfrac{1}{nc+1}
\to 1
$
as $n \to \infty$.

From
"What is Mathematics"
by Courant and Robbins.

Read this book!